# Flutter: How to limit number of fields from a document

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, pagination

I have an app that stores data in a structure which looks like the following:

> Collection > Document (each user has their own) > then a bunch of fields

Each time the user makes a new entry I add another field to the document. I do not know the name of the fields as they are named by the time they are created. I want to implement pagination but do not know how to limit the document to give only give me x number of fields in the document.

How can I limit the number of fields returned from a document?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Each time the user makes a new entry I add another field to the document.

If you add a new field to a document, please note that the documents have limits. You are limited to [1 MiB (1,048,576 bytes) per document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quotas). So most likely you should add that data as a new document rather than a new property within a document.

> I do not know the name of the fields as they are named by the time they are created.

Be aware to stay below the maximum limit.

> I want to implement pagination but do not know how to limit the document to give only give me x number of fields in the document.

That's not how pagination works. You can paginate the result of a Query, not the document itself. Meaning that you can perform a query and all the results that are returned can be dived in smaller chunks. I can see no reason why would you paginate data from a single document. If this is your requirement, then get the data from the document as a Map by calling getData(), iterate the entries, and add them to a List. Then simply paginate that list. But I repeat, you should paginate documents using query cursors as explained in the docs:

- https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/query-cursors

Comment: Oh ok, thanks! I'll seperate them into their own documents then. Is there a more elegant way to seperate them into their own documents instead of making Collection > users' documents > sub collection > entry documents?

Comment: It doesn't really matter if you using top-level collections or subcollections as long the queries that you perform satisfy your needs.